# Problems! Entity data are not fetched using data access object (dao) and JPA?

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, dao

I have this Dao which get events according to the user id. It return the events object.

```
public enum Dao {
INSTANCE;
public List<EventsDetail> getevents(String userId) {
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("select t from EventsDetail t where t.MemberId = :userId");
    q.setParameter("userId", userId);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<EventsDetail> events = q.getResultList();
    return events;
  }
}
```

here i have this jsp page which call dao as i have import the dao class. here i have used try and catch to throw exception where i get null pointer exception.

```
<%
Dao dao = Dao.INSTANCE;
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
List<EventsDetail> events = new ArrayList();
if (user != null) {
  pageContext.setAttribute("user", user);
  events = dao.getevents(user.getUserId());
    %>
}....

 <% 
try{
for (EventsDetail event : events) {
    pageContext.setAttribute("title", event.Title());
    pageContext.setAttribute("place", event.getPlace());
    pageContext.setAttribute("category", event.Category());
    pageContext.setAttribute("cdate", event.Cdate());
 %>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="r1"><%=count%></span>
                <span class="r2">${fn:escapeXml(cdate)}</span>
                <span class="r2">${fn:escapeXml(place)}</span>
                <span class="r3">${fn:escapeXml(title)}</span>
                <span class="r4">${fn:escapeXml(category)}</span>

            </div>
 <% }  
          } catch (Exception e)
          {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
          }
             %>
```

the problem is that i get just empty data from the datastore where data are already persent in the datastore.

Comment: Is there any reason to use ENUM ? Just curious... :)

Comment: i am just beginner leaner to create this kind of project from this link (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html). As he have used the enum. SO i am using to learn some thing new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `getEvents` method.

you can try doing the following:

```
public enum Dao {
INSTANCE;
public List<EventsDetail> getevents(String userId) {
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
    Query q = em.createQuery("select t from EventsDetail t where t.MemberId = " + userId);
    q.setParameter("userId", userId);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<EventsDetail> events = q.getResultList();
    return events;
  }
}
```

and make sure you are passing correct userId.